# vbscript to Delphi

Tags: c#, delphi, vbscript

I have a VBScript which I'm converting to Delphi.
I'm struggling with these 2 lines.
Can someone explain what do they do:

```
init_lib.Flags(&H7FFF) 
init_lib.Environment(1)
```

Couldn't find any documentation related to the 1st line.
I kept the 2nd line as it is in Delphi but not sure how to convert the 1st line.

What's their equivalent in Delphi (or C#) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&H` is a VB shorthand for hexadecimal value.

In order to use the value in Delphi you have to use the string without the prefix or to convert the string `'7FFF'` to a decimal value: you know what type of argument `Flags` accepts.

The `'7FFF'` hex string corresponds to the decimal `32767`.

The shorthand for hexadecimal values in Delphi is `$`: `$7FFF` evaluates to an `Integer` type that can be assigned to a variable or a constant directly.

Comment: Or just use Delphi syntax for [hexadecimal numerals](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Fundamental_Syntactic_Elements#Numerals): `$7FFF`

Comment: @TOndrej was my 1st choice but i became crazy with `$h7fff` and forgot about it!

Comment: Thank you very much fantaghirocco & TOndrej.  That works. Do you know what those settings do ?

Comment: hard to say it without knowing the type of `init_lib` or the context: it seems a DLL initialization... something COM related maybe

Comment: It is COM related.  Thanks

Comment: I don't have a clue what type of object your `init_lib` variable is  - it should be an `OleVariant` but I can't know what kind of object it points to; I'm not a COM expert and I cannot even guess the type the properties belong to, I'm sorry :( But you might consider to ask another question adding further details in it